Hive: Dropping partitions not satisfying the condition
I'm trying to come up with a solution to my problem:
I need to delete all data in a partitioned (managed/external) table in Hive that don't satisfy the condition applied on other non-partition column.
I've tried to achieve this by
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_name PARTITION (partition_cols, ...) 
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE /condition on other_col/ 

But it doesn't overwrite the partitions that are not in the dataset returned by select and I understand why, this is basically what I have:  Insert overwrite on partitioned table is not deleting the existing data , but I'll copy it here:
Table definition
CREATE TABLE `cities_red`(                                                              
  `cityid` int,                                                                         
  `city` string)                                                                        
PARTITIONED BY (                                                                        
  `state` string)                                                                       
ROW FORMAT SERDE                                                                        
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'                                           
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT                                                                   
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'                                     
OUTPUTFORMAT                                                                            
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'                                    
TBLPROPERTIES (                                                                         
  'auto.purge'='true',                                                                  
  'last_modified_time'='1555591782',                                                    
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1555591782');  

Table Data



cities_red.cityid
cities_red.city
cities_red.state




13
KARNAL
HARYANA


13
KARNAL
HARYANA


1
Nagpur
MH


22
Mumbai
MH


22
Mumbai
MH


755
BPL
MP


755
BPL
MP


10
BANGLORE
TN


10
BANGLORE
TN


10
BANGLORE
TN


10
BANGLORE
TN


12
NOIDA
UP


12
NOIDA
UP



And query  insert overwrite table cities_red partition (state) select * from cities_red where city !='NOIDA';
doesn't remove the rows since the partition is not selected.
This question explains the behavior, but how can I achieve that those partitions not in select dataset are also deleted?
The context is that im rendering those queries in my Scala application for data management. And it would be great if there is a way to achieve this behavior using primary sql queries without manual partition deletion (like alter table drop partition (state = 'UP'); because the number of partitions may be arbitrary and manual manipulation seems to be an overkill. I've tried a naive solution like creating temporary table for that, but it seems like not the best idea, since I may not have rights to create tables.
Any help would be very much appreciated!
